# What is OBJECT_KEY in aws-sdk-php-laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using "aws-sdk-php-laravel" package in my laravel 5 project. which used amazonS3 for storage. But what is OBJECT_KEY and where to get it.

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->createClient('s3');
$s3->putObject(array(
'Bucket'     => 'YOUR_BUCKET',
'Key'        => 'YOUR_OBJECT_KEY',
'SourceFile' => '/the/path/to/the/file/you/are/uploading.ext',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's name of your file on `S3`.

You can check it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject).

Answer (score 0):

It's the name of the file on S3. Just to make things a little easier to understand, don't think of S3 as a filesystem. Think of it as a key data store.

So you have a key, the 'file name', and the data associated with it. In this instance it is your 'SourceFile' variable which is a location to a file on your local filesystem (not s3). All content in that source file will be uploaded against the key name.